# Set a breakpoint on memory address when it is being freed: lldb

Tags: xcode, free, lldb

My iOS application is crashing on memory address when it is trying to double free that address. I have tried multiple ways trying to know what is causing double free, Ex: watchpoint or enable Zombies or using Instruments in Xcode but no avail. Is there any way I can set some kind of breakpoint on that memory address so that it will hit when it is being freed and I will get to know who is trying to free it? I have also tried to put a Symbolic breakpoint on the free method but it hangs the application because of continuous free calls.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using ASAN?  You turn it on in the Run Scheme of your project (it's the first item "Address Sanitizer").  It will force a rebuild, since it instruments your code.  But the instrumentation it inserts in your code will detect the double free, stop the process there, and show you the call sites for the malloc & the first free event for that address.  This is a pretty helpful tool for detecting memory problems of this sort.

Answer (score 3):

You need a conditional breakpoint. Create the symbolic breakpoint on `free`, but then right-click it and click "Edit Breakpoint...".

You'll need to set a condition here so that the breakpoint only gets called for your specific argument. Use LLDB's `$arg1` variable to refer to the first parameter of `free` (your memory block) and set something like this for its condition:

```
$arg1 == 0x0000000000001234
```

but use the actual pointer value you're interested in.

Continue. Your breakpoint will only trigger when the block of memory at that specific pointer is being freed.

Comment: This is a literal answer to your question, but Jim's answer above is probably better to achieve what you want.

Comment: This answer is also useful, since ASAN doesn't fit every usecase and you can't always use it. For example I had a Qt app, which pretty much wouldn't run at all when built with ASAN.